# DragGestureRecognizer in Xamarin.Forms sets the background color to the theme color when dragging an element

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, drag-and-drop

I am creating a mobile app using Xamarin.Forms.
We need to implement drag-and-drop handling, and we have implemented drag-and-drop handling for the target element by referring to the following page.

[Add drag and drop gesture recognizers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/gestures/drag-and-drop)

### Problem

**While dragging an element, the background color of the dragging element becomes the theme color.**

Below is a screenshot of the actual application being created.
The premise is that the screen background itself is blue, with a round image and text.
The figure below is when the theme color is light (in case of dark, the background will be black)

(before dragging)
[before dragging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3TDzE.jpg)

(while dragging)
[dragging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oi5xC.jpg)

#### Code

```cs
<CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                <DragGestureRecognizer DragStartingCommand="{Binding BindingContext.DragCommand, Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ContentPage}}}" DragStartingCommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
            </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
            <Frame>
                <Image Source="{Binding ImagePath,Mode=OneWay}" Aspect="AspectFill"/>
            </Frame>
            <Label Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Name,Mode=OneWay}"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
```

As you can see in the image while dragging, a green plus icon is added that I did not add myself, so I am thinking that the control was added by someone else while dragging, and the area with the background color as the theme color was added at that time.

I also looked at some of the code on the Xamarin.Forms Github, but I couldn't figure out the cause.

#### What I tried

- Set BackgroundColor of Grid to Transparent.

  - No effect.
- Set BackgroundColor of Grid to Red.

  - The background color is now Red both before and during dragging.

#### version and platform

- Xamarin.Forms : 5.0.0.2083
- iOS

---

I'd like to keep the background color transparent while dragging without changing it.
Please let me know if there is any other information you need.
Please help me.

Comment: Seems like it might be a bug in XF. Can you test on Android emulator as well?  Would be useful to know if this symptom only occurs on iOS.  Another test that would be informative: Make another page that uses that Grid directly on the page, instead of as an ItemTemplate. Perhaps it is cloned differently when not inside a list.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Created a sample application [Xamarin.Forms_-DragGestureRecognizerSample](https://github.com/takecx/Xamarin.Forms_-DragGestureRecognizerSample) . After testing on both iOS and Android, I found that this event occurs only on iOS. I also tried placing the Grid directly on the page, and the situation was the same. (The phenomenon occurs only on iOS).

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve [iOS before dragging](https://github.com/takecx/Xamarin.Forms_-DragGestureRecognizerSample/blob/main/images/ios_before_dragging.png) [iOS drag started](https://github.com/takecx/Xamarin.Forms_-DragGestureRecognizerSample/blob/main/images/ios_drag_started.png) [iOS drag moving](https://github.com/takecx/Xamarin.Forms_-DragGestureRecognizerSample/blob/main/images/ios_drag_moving.png)

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve [Android before dragging](https://github.com/takecx/Xamarin.Forms_-DragGestureRecognizerSample/blob/main/images/android_before_dragging.png) [Android dragging](https://github.com/takecx/Xamarin.Forms_-DragGestureRecognizerSample/blob/main/images/android_dragging.png)

Comment: I agree: that seems to be a bug in XF on iOS. Please create a new issue at https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues. Link to your sample app repo, and link to this SO question. Also add link here to the new issue. Perhaps someone knows a work-around.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Created an [issue](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/14878).Thanks for your advice.